# Does this code deletes duplicates?

Tags: mysql, linux

I want to use this to get data from row out of mysql database into text files (one entry under another, 50 entries per file):

```
$ mysql --user=XXX --password=XXX --batch --skip-column-names \
 -e "SELECT userid, displayname FROM Users" stackoverflowdb | \
split -l 50 -a 5 - "result."
```

but I also don't want to copy duplicate entries to these files. Will this code remove duplicates or do i need to add something to it to don't copy duplicate entries?

Comment: Are you referring to duplicate entries in the Users table?

Comment: yes, i don't want duplicate entries from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the SQL to use the DISTINCT directive

e.g.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT userid,displayname FROM Users
```

will ensure that only unique combinations of userid and displayname are selected.

However this will not prevent userids that have identical displaynames.

Comment: great, thanks. upvoted. just wanted to make sure... text files will be created in directory i cd to?

Comment: I think split will create them in the current working directory by default, yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid,displayname FROM Users
```

.. or outside the database

```
mysql --user=XXX --password=XXX --batch --skip-column-names \
 -e "SELECT userid, displayname FROM Users" stackoverflowdb | \
sort -u | \
split -l 50 -a 5 - "result."
```